# Tabular with prescribed width and options

Tags: tables, spacing, cv

My purpose is to reproduce this document :

[image]

I want to create a tabular, but I want the first column to be, for example, of 6 centimeters in width. Other point : sometimes I need a lot of room in a line, to reprduce this :

[image]

Can somebody help me with doing this, or even help me create a command to do so, so that my CV writing will be easier and "automatic" (LaTeX is designed for it I think)

I didn't found anything on the web, maybe because I don't know what to search for.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you've tried so far; even partial and non-working code might be helpful.

Comment: I think you should take alook at some specialised packages, e.g. `moderncv`.

Comment: You haven't found a LaTeX-CV-related thing on the web? I cannot believe that. There are hundreds of things out there.

Comment: @Johannes_B : I found hundreds of cv created with moderncv or not, but none were what I was looking for so I started to create mine.

Comment: @Mico : this question is now solved, but next time I will show my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look into using a `tabularx` environment with two columns. The first could be, say, 6cm wide, and width of the second would be the residual, i.e., the overall width of the textblock minus the width of the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\sffamily % switch to sans-serif
\noindent
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{6cm} L @{}}
\textsl{Langues}\\[2.5mm]
\textbf{Anglais} & Parlé couramment\\
\textbf{Italien} & Débutant\\
\textbf{Chinois} & Débutant\\[5mm]
\textsl{Informatique} & Word, Excel, PowerPoint, LaTeX, Scilab, FreeFam++, Matlab\\[5mm]
\textsl{Autres activités} & Piano Jazz, sports dont natation à raison de 6h par semaine\\[5mm]
\qquad\textbf{Février 2008} & \textbf{\em Première expérience à SARL PCP en tant qu'ouvrier}\\
& Stage en tant qu'ouvier dans l'entreprise familiale qui m'a fait comprendere le quotidien ouvrier. A débouché sur la livraison d'une maison.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps loading `ltablex` instead if it has to break across pages?

Comment: @Bernard - A good suggestion. Let's see if the OP weighs in with more information.

Comment: It works perfectly, just an other question : why using lmodern package ? Thanks.

Comment: @M.LTA - Glad my answer is useful. :-) About loading the `lmodern` package: The Latin Modern font family has much better accent placement than Computer Modern (the default font family). To see for yourself, I suggest you comment out the instruction `\usepackage{lmodern}` and look at the `e` and `a` letters with sharp and grave accents. Of course, you are free to choose whatever font family best suits your needs.

Comment: Oh now I see the difference, latin modern seems better, especially for French ! The one thing I need is now finding how to justify the text in a column environement, I will try to do it on my own.

Comment: @M.LTA The definition of the `L` column makes it non-justified. If you leave out the `>{stuff}` part, it will be.

Comment: @Johannes_B : the command line : 
`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{6cm} XX @{}}`
works, but I do not know if it is a good syntax.

Comment: @M.LTA - What Johannes_B is suggesting is to replace `L` with `X`, not with `XX`. The single-`X` variant is definitely OK, syntaxwise. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something already with tabular, like

```
\begin{tabular}{r|l|p{5cm}}
    pièce & fichier & very long blablablablabla\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

and the 3rd column will be 5 cm wide.

Comment: To an extent, this is already covered by [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298765/5764).